# In Hibernate HQL, how do I left join fetch a subclass' linked entities when multiple subclasses have a property with the same name?

Tags: java, hibernate

**Summary**

In Hibernate, I am trying to LEFT JOIN FETCH properties from subclasses of a main class, where multiple subclasses have properties with the same name. Hibernate, though, is only fetching the first subclass' linked entities, and not the others.

**Background**

I am modelling genomic features (genes, transcripts and exons) and genetic variants in a Hibernate-based system. Genes, Transcripts and Exons are all subclasses of GenomicFeature, and Variants can each have zero-to-many GenomicFeatures. Genes, in turn, have zero-to-many transcripts -- as do Exons -- and Transcripts have zero-to-many Genes and Exons. Each of these relationships are fetched lazily. Sometimes, though, I want to fetch a variant and all of its genomic features, as well as all of the genomic features linked from the immediate genomic features. Eg, I want to fetch a specific variant, the Genes/Transcripts/Exons associated with the variant, all the Transcripts of the genes, all the Genes&Exons of the Transcripts, and all the Transcripts of the Exons.

**The problem**

When I do a query for the above, it works except that the Transcripts for the Genes are not fetched, only the Exon's  Transcripts are fetched. I assume this is because the property -- gene.transcripts and exon.transcripts -- shares the same name.

**What I've tried**

The main query, in a PagingAndSortingRepository, is below

```
    @Query("SELECT v FROM Variant v"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH v.variantGenomicFeatures AS vgf"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH vgf.genomicFeature AS gf LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.genes LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.exons LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.transcripts"
        + " WHERE"
        + "     v.id = (:id)")
public Variant findOneByIdAndGenomicFeaturesEagerly(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

I've tried joining genomicFeature twice, once for Genes and once for Transcripts&Exons, but this doesn't work.

I've tried only selecting Genes (`WHERE TYPE(gf) = Gene`), but looking at the query it generates, it still joins only the Exon's Transcripts and then returns the Genes.

Comment: try to do it in two steps...

Comment: did you try with `JOIN FETCH` instead of `LEFT JOIN FETCH`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It just works. I had a syntax error in my HQL.

When a discriminated subclass has properties/column that are not in the root class all properties of all distriminator subclasses are accessible in the HQL when using the root class in the FROM statement.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try myself but maybe with alias on fetch clause can help Hibernate to distinguish field ?

```
LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.genes as g 
LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.exons as e 
LEFT JOIN FETCH gf.transcripts as t
```